# Custom resolution - Windows 7 - no drivers

Tags: windows, drivers, resolution, vga

I'm having some problems with my VGA card. When I enable my VGA drivers and boot windows up they crash and I get message that the problem occured with atimdag.sys drivers or smth like that. I'm gettin BSOD all the time, unless I go to control panel and I disable drivers manually. I can live with disabled drivers just fine(I'm already used to it in quite some time) but the annoying problem is my display resolution. I can not set my res to anything higher than 1024x768. I was wondering if it's possible to change resolution to my native displays resolution without drivers?

I've been trying to find something that would work w/o drivers, but with no luck(I've found many of solutions how to do it with working drivers, but as you know I can not enable my drivers).

So please, maybe someone could help me and tell me how to set custom resolution?

Comment: Are you sure that you have the right drivers?

Comment: What video card are you using?

Comment: I'm have  ATI MOBILITY RADEON HD 3450, and NB it self is Dell Studio 1535

Comment: 32 bit or 64 bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have custom resolution without the proper drivers.

Try the latest **stable** drivers. Or go through the driver archives and test each one of them.

If you are using a branded machine(HP,etc). Download the driver's from the OEM, not the video card manufacturer.

Next try the CD that came with the machine/video card.

If that doesn't work, try the video card manufacturer's website. (ATI)

Remove Catalyst Control Center and just install the ATI driver.

Check the AMD website if there is any hotfix available for your card.

Comment: I've done it all, tried to install all kind of different drivers, nothing helped. And last, when I tried to instal Linux Ubuntu, same happened, after booting my NB crashed. So I assume that something with my VGA is broken and for that reasons its constantly crashing.
PS. it was working just fine for long time, until one day I got first crash. During that time I didnt manually update or change VGA drivers. And I assume windows did not either?

Comment: @VytautasButkus The Linux kernel generally packs generic video drivers, so you don't have to install any explicitly. If it crashes even in Ubuntu, then maybe the problem is hardware. 

Have you checked temperatures? Does it overheat? Had any overclocking enabled?

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure that it's hardware. But it can't be temperature, because same happens even if I turn the computer while it's brought cold from outside. And for some reason on windows with drivers disabled I can still use my NB

Comment: Try cleaning the video card points with rubbing alcohol(the strip that goes inside). And try to get rid of the dust(if any). Other than that, I can't see anything except replacement. Or using without being able to change resolutions. You might want to give DriverMax a try.